# Probability enhancement for bosons: Probability goes over 1?

Tags: bosons

It is said that if there is already n bosons in a particular quantum state, the probability of another boson joining them is (n+1) times larger than it would have been otherwise. But if we apply this rule to calculate probability for one horizontally (H) polarized photon to join a bunch of n=99 diagonally (D) polarized photons, we'll get (99+1) 1/2 = 50. What's wrong?

Comment: Would you like me to merge your two accounts?

Answer (score 1):

In general photon number [is not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) conserved and the word 'otherwise' is unclear. We could say there is an infinite set of photons for you to steal one to add to the collection of $n$ photons. Anyway, there exists a set of probabilities $p_i$ such that $p_i / p_{i+1} = i + 1$. You wanted the inverse ratio but we can easily label any set of probabilities in reverse, and shift the index. For example, this rule is satisfied for $p_i = e^{-1} (n!)^{-1}$. The factor of

$$e = 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \cdots = \sum_i \frac{1}{i!}$$

normalizes the sum so that it satisfies the probability rule $\sum_i p_i = 1$.